# Had water running through the water source to the fridge but not anymore. disconnected shut off valve but no water coming out?

Tags: plumbing

Had water running through the water source to the fridge but not anymore.  disconnected shut off valve but no water coming out?

Comment: Is there another valve some where? Is there something else recently that happened or was done in the house. Something triggered this

Comment: Is this a saddle valve? One that punctures a pipe? And a flex line to the fridge. If so there is probably a chunk of scale plugging the tiny orifice. Saddle valves should be outlawed in my opinion because they plug up or flood. This has been my experience more times than I can remember. Sometimes cycling the piercing point will clear it but have a bucket ready and some one ready to turn the main off if it fails.